# sshpass installation

Tags: bash, ssh, unix, sudoers

I want to use passwordless SSH for logging in. I used `sshpass` to achieve this.

The problem is when I am trying to install `sshpass` through `sudo apt-get install sshpass`. It asks for password.

After I enter the password, the following message is getting displayed:

```
Santosh_Nayak05 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I desperately want to use `sshpass`. I am new to Unix. Can any body tell me what is `sudoers` file and how I can install and use `sshpass`?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things you don't have `sudo` access to install `sshpass` in your environment (Is this a school's server you are on?)

Your alternatives are:

- [Set up ssh keys](http://paulkeck.com/ssh/) for password-less ssh (preferred)exp
- Write a [expect script](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to auto-send the password for you

Comment: thank you for your reply . actually me working in  a small project which uses terminal for interact with server.is there any way to install sshpass . As  i am new to unix http://paulkeck.com/ssh/ looks complicated to me and expect script is also beyond me.

Comment: yes me working in a office server where i don't have the sudo access